# If Role Not Found Create New Role | Discord.js

Tags: discord, discord.js

Hi I am trying to make a color system for my bot but the command creates duplicate roles. Heres the Basics behind my code. I want it to check if the role is already present then don't make it again. How would i do this

```
const user = message.author;
        const member = message.guild.member(user);

       if (member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR')) {
        message.guild.roles.create({
            data: {
                name: '#Red',
                color: 'ff0000',
                permissions: 0,
            }
        })
        message.channel.send('**Red Color Has Been Created!**')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
if (message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name == "#Red")) return false; // The role already exists.

message.guild.roles.create({ // Creating the role since it doesn't exist.
    data: {
        name: "#Red",
        color: "#ff0000",
        permissions: 0
    }
}).then(role => {
    message.channel.send(`Role \`${role.name}\` created!`);
});
```